I Want to navigate to widget after notification tapped when app is closed (flutter_local_notifications package)
I used flutter_local_notifications package and i want to navigate to widget after notification tapped when app is closed.
This is my source code :
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:js';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_local_notifications/flutter_local_notifications.dart';
import 'package:second_project/Screens/PrivateUserChat.dart';

class NotificationManager {
  static FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin? flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin;

  @pragma('vm:entry-point')
  static void notificationTapBackground(
      NotificationResponse notificationResponse) {
    Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
      return PrivateUserChatScreen(
        receiver_username: 'username',
      );
    }));
  }

  static Initialize() async {
    flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin = FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

    const initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin?.initialize(
      const InitializationSettings(
        android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
      ),
      onDidReceiveBackgroundNotificationResponse: notificationTapBackground,
    );
  }

  static Future<void> ShowNotification(String msg, {String title = ""}) async {
    var androidChannelSpecifics = AndroidNotificationDetails(
      'CHANNEL_ID',
      'CHANNEL_NAME',
      //"CHANNEL_DESCRIPTION",
      importance: Importance.max,
      priority: Priority.high,
      playSound: true,
      timeoutAfter: 5000,
      styleInformation: DefaultStyleInformation(true, true),
    );
    var platformChannelSpecifics =
        NotificationDetails(android: androidChannelSpecifics);
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin!.show(
      0, // Notification ID
      title, // Notification Title
      msg, // Notification Body, set as null to remove the body
      platformChannelSpecifics,
      payload: 'New Payload', // Notification Payload
    );
  }
}


But i cannot access to context in Navigator.push(context,....
Please help.

You can not route from that isolate function. When your notification opens your app, check your
notificationTapBackground(NotificationResponse notificationResponse) function. If your notificationResponse is not null, then you are good to go to the next step.
So, if you local notification starts your app, you can call the below Future function to get your notification details from any screen you like:
final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();

Then route to your desired page from details from your notification. Obviously, if you are doing the above function in a screen you should have context.
Edited answer because OP wanted source code
So in your NotificationManager class, add the following function:
void checkIfNotificationLaunchedApp() async {
    final NotificationAppLaunchDetails? notificationAppLaunchDetails =
        await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.getNotificationAppLaunchDetails();


    if (notificationAppLaunchDetails != null) {
      if (notificationAppLaunchDetails.didNotificationLaunchApp) {
         //Do something here as app is opened through notification
         //DO any app routing here if you want
         print('My notification details: ${notificationAppLaunchDetails.notificationResponse!}');
      }
    }
  }

Let say you want to access the above function in your homescreen:
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  const Home({super.key});

  @override
  State<Home> createState() => _SState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    NotificationManager.checkIfNotificationLaunchedApp();
    super.initState();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      
    );
  }
}


@md-kamrul-amin Is it possible to write the complete source code?

Check edited answer

@programmer1360 If this answer helped you, be courteous enough to mark it as an answer.
